# Can I make one function for all activity, to play, pause music

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, singleton, android-music-player

First Activity

```
package com.example.birthdaywish;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    
    public void wishButton(View view) {
        final EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName);
        String name = editText.getText().toString();

        Intent intent =  new Intent(this, screen2.class);
        intent.putExtra("name", name);



        startActivity(intent);

        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.happy_birthday_song);
        mediaPlayer.start(); // no need to call prepare(); create() does that for you




    }

}
```

Above is my first activity. In which i have played music on button click at the same time button click will also open second activity.

Second Activity

```
package com.example.birthdaywish;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class screen2 extends AppCompatActivity {


    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen2);
        TextView enteredName = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
        enteredName.setText("Happy Birthday " +name);


    }



    public void displayMessage(View view) {
      
        

    }
}
```

Now when the display message button is pressed, I want to stop the music that is played in first activity. Or can I do it in any other way like, creating a common function for Musicplayer having start and stop method and I can call them whenever I want to start or stop music in any activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see two options:

1. Make `MediaPlayer` static object.
2. Consider implementing Single Activity approach. You will have two fragments and shared `ViewModel` in which you can access `MediaPlayer`.

Comment: Sir, I am a beginner, and it's my first project. I have started to learn android development by going project. So can you provide me with the code?

Answer (score 0):

Make a Utils class in which you will create the Global method for playing & pausing the Music player.

In that Utils class:

```
private static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private static int seek_position;

public static void playMedia(Context context, int music) {
    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying() && mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, music);
    try {
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });
}
```

Use this method whenever you want to play the media like this:

```
Utils.playMedia(this, R.raw.happy_birthday_song);
```

Now, if you want to implement Global pause, resume & stop functionality, then use this (create these methods in the same Utils class)

```
public static void pauseMedia(Context context) {
    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying() && mediaPlayer != null) {
        seek_position = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }
}

public static void resumeMedia(Context context) {
    if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying() && mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(seek_position);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}

public static void stopMedia(Context context) {
    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying() && mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
    }
}
```

Use these methods wherever you want in your app just by calling them like the first method.

NOTE : The difference here between `pause()` & `stop()` is that you have to prepare the mediaplayer again if you use `stop()`, whereas `pause()` doesn't require it.